# Changing the background image of <html> with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know it's possible to change the background image for `body` or `div` tags, but is it possible to add or change the background image for the `html` tag?

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
$("html").css('background', 'url(../images/myImage.jpg)');
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('body').parent().css('background', 'url(imagePath)')`. It should work.

Comment: $("html").css('background', 'url(images/myImage.jpg)'); It works fine with out '../'.

Answer (score 0):

This method is perfec

```
var id_of_div ="contenedor";
document.getElementById(id_of_div).style.backgroundImage='http://conectica.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/youtube-ios.png';
```

that's all